# Trying to stabilize a video with FFMPEG so that it looks like it was taken with a tripod

Tags: ffmpeg, stabilisation

I have tried to stabilize this video [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-oR-ZHEodg) using ffmpeg. I have tried deshake and vidstabdetect/bidstabtransform.  I would like the outcome to look like it was taken from a tripod

I have tried it with these settings:

```
ffmpeg -t 5 -i GOPR7182.MP4 -vf vidstabdetect=stepsize=32:shakiness=10:accuracy=10:result=transform_vectors.trf -f null -
```

And settings like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf vidstabtransform=tripod=1:interpol=bicubic:input=input.trf,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 -c:v libx264 -tune film -preset veryslow -crf 12 -x264opts no-fast-pskip -c:a copy input-stab.mkv
```

And lots of variation on shakiness/accuracy/stepsize.  The results are all similar where the motion is reduced but it still shakes.  Does anybody know of settings that would help me get the tripod like results or is this to much to ask given the motion in the video?

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: What motion?!?  I'm sorry.  I've answered this question so many times, I was expecting to see a handheld shot of an earthquake on horseback, and give my usual spiel about parallax and motion blur.  (here, eg https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29671/is-video-stabilization-during-recording-better-than-stabilizing-a-shot-in-post-p)

Comment: Or here https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12840/using-smartphone-sensors-to-stabilise-dslr-video-in-post/12844#12844